# Как получить подстроку после введенного символа C++?

Tags: c++, алгоритм, строки, char

```
#include <cstring> 
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std; 
  
int main() 
{ 
    // Take any string 
    string s = "abcdefghijk"; 
  
    // Find position of 'd' using find() 
    int pos = s.find("d"); 
  
    // Copy substring after pos 
    string sub = s.substr(pos + 1); 
  
    // prints the result 
    cout << "String is: " << sub; 
  
    return 0; 
}
```

мне нужно тот же результат но только с выводами (input)

Примеры

```
INPUT:  abcdefghijk
INPUT:  d
OUTPUT: efghijk
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Вводим строку и символ.
- Находим позицию символа в строке.
- Если не нашли, то позиция принимает значение `std::string::npos`.
  Значит, если позиция `pos` не равен этому значению, то символ найден. Иначе выводим, что не нашли.

И, ввиду заранее выполненного постинкремента(pos++), получаем строку    после этого символа, передавая в substr эту позицию  позицию(позиция    следующего символа после найденного).

```
string s;
char d;
cin >> s >> d;
size_t pos = s.find(d);
if(pos++ != s.npos)
   cout << "String is: " << s.substr(pos);
else
    cout << "\n!!!!not found\n";
```

Comment: AR Hovsepyan как сделать чтоб в output было пусто когда вводится символ
например std::cin >> abcd
std::cin >> %

сейчас программа возвращает abcd

Comment: сделайте так:  больше и лучше изучайте, А пока... я добавил в ответ `else`

Comment: не работает этот вариант...

Comment: я просто забыл переписать инициализацию

Comment: Но, думаю, чаще лучше получить всю строку, когда не найдено, так что первоначальный вариант мне больше   нравился

Comment: AR Hovsepyan еще одна просьба!  объясните пожалуйста как этот кот работает

Comment: объяснения добавил в ответ

Answer (score 1):

выводим строку с помощью for_each с начальным итератором смещенным на позицию после необходимой буквы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
  std::string text;
  std::cin >> text;
  char letter;
  std::cin >> letter;

  auto pos = text.find(letter);
  
  if (pos != text.npos) {
    std::for_each(text.begin() + pos + 1, text.end(),
      [](auto symb) {std::cout << symb;});
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: мне нужно  чтоб в std::cin написать например abcdefghijk
потом в std::cin вводить букву d
и в std::cout получать efghijk

Comment: @Vardan поправил

Comment: спасибо Ildar ! а как сделать  когда вместо буквы выводишь символ или цифра, программа ничего не возвращал??

Comment: использовать std::for_each и лямбда выражение для получения подстроки? ..  Это платить 100 баксов, чтобы реставрировать 100 рублевую

Comment: @ARHovsepyan хах согласен, забыл про substr что-то...